# Want to format an Unknown Disk

Tags: hard-drive, format

Have a disk attached to ubuntu linux computer. It is reported as unknown. I have been trying to format it. So far everything I have tried has failed. Is there any hope of formatting this disk?

#### Additional information posted as an answer:

First of all. From the GUI specs of the drive.

```
Model: ST3500418AS (CC44)
S/N: SVM3QFD7
Assessment: Disk is OK, 1000 bad Sectors
Size: 500 GB
below Volumes
Size: 500 GB
Contents: Unknown
Device: /dev/sdb
```

When format is run from here with parameters

```
Erase - Don't overwrite existing data (Quick)
Partitioning - No partitioning (Empty)
```

Does nothing, no errors

When I run the following

```
sudo parted -a apt /dev/sdb mkpart primary NTFS 0% 100%
```

Does nothing, no errors

When I run the following

```
sudo mkfs.ntfs /dev/sdb
```

Does nothing, no errors

Everything I have tried I get the same results. Nothing.

The Ubuntu ver. 22.04.2 LTS

Got gparted up and running. It has been scanning /dev/sdb for more than 4 hours this morning with nothing happening. Bottom of apt a red bar sliding from one side to the other, back and forth. I don't believe the disk is damaged physically, but appears there is not way to format. Am I wrong, any other suggestions?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu? Disk Info? Might the disk be damaged? A complete list of everything you have tried and the errors.

Comment: Normally, the first thing you need to do is make a partition table, then add partitions, then format a partition.  parted uses the "mklabel" command to make a partition table.

Comment: Could you share the output from:    `lsblk | grep -w disk`  AND from  `lsblk /dev/sdb`  ?

Answer (score 3):

You can use gparted tool to format the disk. Gparted is GUI based utility for disk management operations.

```
sudo apt-get install gparted
```

Gparted runs with the sudo authority, select the unknown disk on the right upper corner like /dev/sd* depends on your number of disks. Right click and format it according to your preferred file system.